# Running DRF endpoints in a venv with gunicorn

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gunicorn, python-venv

I have some APIs implemented with DRF and I want those to run in a venv. I am using gunicorn. I run gunicorn like this:

```
/path_to_venv/bin/gunicorn
```

But in the API code I log `os.getenv('VIRTUAL_ENV')` and it's None. Is that valid evidence that the code is not running in the venv? If so, how can I force it to run in the venv? If not, how can I validate that it is running in the venv?

Comment: Check `sys.executable` path. If it points to venv python, you're fine. You're most likely fine, since your imports do not fail.

Comment: Will check that. Imports succeeding is not evidence as the needed packages may exist outside of the venv.

Comment: Thanks, sys.executable points to the venv python so I'm good.